# Vda devices in podman

Tags: docker, podman

I have a podman image with Ubuntu 18.04 and if I run a container with the command:

```
podman run -it <my image> /bin/bash
```

and I run the command:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

I see the following:

```
root@0382d078cd30:/# cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

  11        0    1048575 sr0
 252        0  104857600 vda
 252        1       1024 vda1
 252        2     130048 vda2
 252        3     393216 vda3
 252        4  104332271 vda4
```

Can anyone explain to me what are these devices? I tried to do some search but no luck. The reason I want to know this is because I need to test some commands like: parted, mkfs.ext4, tune2fs, and e2fsck on the /dev/vda1 device. However, I don't know how these virtual devices are mapped on my host system. I'm afraid that formatting the /dev/vda1 device with the mkfs.ext4 command I lost some data on my MacOS host.

I didn't map explicitely these devices with something on my host, so I think that podman created them by default and map them on my host in some way.
Is it safe to run the above command against these virtual devices or is there the risk I break something on my host?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: A Docker container is isolated from the host system environment, and you can't access the host disk devices.  (That would be one way to escape the container environment and generally compromise the host.)  You need to run system-administration commands like `parted` or `mkfs` directly on the host.

Comment: You could create an empty file inside your container and mount that as a loopback mount (like you might with an .iso file). That might require some extra cgroup permissions though - never tried it.